# Releasing javascript library... how should I handle the external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, package, gruntjs, bower

I'm releasing a javascript library.

My library depends on other libraries.

Some of those libraries are available through `npm`, some through `bower`.

How can I release the compiled version of my library? Should I contain the compressed dependencies' code as well? To achieve that, should I use something like `grunt`?

Comment: I would not only offer a version of your library that included all the dependent libraries because that messes up people who already have one of those other libraries in their project.

Comment: So how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can distribute it through bower as in bower.json you already describe the dependency if your library meant for Client side script

From http://bower.io/

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "path/to/main.css",
  "ignore": [
    ".jshintrc",
    "**/*.txt"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "<name>": "<version>",
    "<name>": "<folder>",
    "<name>": "<package>"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "<test-framework-name>": "<version>"
  }
}
```

Other wise if it is Server side for `Node` then only `npm` should do the work